# Error displaying image preview in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with ng-file-upload to work with images. In yes I have two options to upload an image for each one. When displaying the first image is displayed in my first ng-model but when I display my second image in my second ng-model it is not shown but it is over write my first ng-model. Then I share my html view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 hide-on-med-and-down">
      <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="file-input">
          <i class="material-icons left teal-text">photo_camera</i>
          Agrega imagen 1...
        </label>
        <input
          id="file-input"
          type="file"
          ngf-select
          ng-model="data.imagen_promocion"
          name="file"
          ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
          accept="image/*"
          ngf-max-size="3MB"
        />
      </div>
      <img ngf-thumbnail="data.imagen_promocion || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="col s12 m12 hide-on-med-and-down">
      <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="file-input">
          <i class="material-icons left teal-text">photo_camera</i>
          Agrega imagen 2...
        </label>
        <input
          id="file-input"
          type="file"
          ngf-select
          ng-model="data.imagen_promocion2"
          name="file"
          ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
          accept="image/*"
          ngf-max-size="3MB"
        />
      </div>
      <img ngf-thumbnail="data.imagen_promocion2 || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

I have seen my error is in css:

```
.image-upload > input{
  display: none;
}
.image-upload i{
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

When I delete this css style it works fine. this is my  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/yjgafc33/7/)

How can I fix this error? I thank you in advance

Comment: Try changing your id and name for second file input to different names

Comment: I get the same error @Vivz

Comment: Looks correct if you have updated the id to be unique, can you show more code on a plnkr?

Comment: When I change my id the window to search image does not appear

Comment: this is my jsfiddle @huanfeng https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/yjgafc33/6/ It looks good but in my project it does not work

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno you fiddle seems working well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your fiddle works fine, there is a problem with the label usage:

```
<label for="file-input">
<input id="file-input">
```

pair should be unique, you shouldn't write double pairs. It will cause some problem there.

Change the label input to below styles, i think it will solve the problem:

```
<label for="file-input-1"></label>
<input id="file-input-1"></input>

<label for="file-input-2"></label>
<input id="file-input-2"></input>
```

It seems fine when i tried on your fiddle:

[image]

Comment: My friend that is true but I found my error, if you can help?
I am going to edit my question

Comment: Have you change the label id and input for to be unique pair?

Comment: yes but that is not the error, the error is in my css if I delete my css all works fine

Comment: ......Since you cannot reproduce the error in fiddle, have you tried plnkr? can you reproduce it on plnkr?

Comment: IT WORKS Thank you  so much my friend :D :D

Comment: The issues is just what i have answered... you really should read my answer carefully :) Please mark the answer as accepted